# Pop up a specific element on hover

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I just want that only individually elements pop up on hover and not all of them.

```js
lists: [{
    fruit: "Apple",
    note: "gg",
    deleteNote: false
  },
  {
    fruit: "Pear",
    note: "gg",
    deleteNote: false
  },
  {
    fruit: "Eggs",
    note: "gg",
    deleteNote: false
  }
]
```

```html
<ul>
  <li v-for="(list,index) in lists" v-bind:key="index" @mouseover="list.deleteNote=true;" @mouseleave="list.deleteNote =false">{{list.fruit}}
    <p v-if="list.deleteNote">{{list.note}}</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not wrong actually. Altering the `deleteNote`s of the elements to observe if it's working more carefully, The following way, it only shows the hovered element's note:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    lists: [{
        fruit: "Apple",
        note: "aa",
        deleteNote: false
      },
      {
        fruit: "Pear",
        note: "pp",
        deleteNote: false
      },
      {
        fruit: "Eggs",
        note: "gg",
        deleteNote: false
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(list,index) in lists" v-bind:key="index" @mouseover="list.deleteNote=true;" @mouseleave="list.deleteNote =false">{{list.fruit}}
      <p v-if="list.deleteNote">{{list.note}}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Sometimes it's better to take a short break, I have no idea why it works know, but thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2):

You only have one flag for `delete` and all the delete buttons are linked to that one.

You can do something like this

```
<ul>
 <li v-for="(list,index) in lists" v-bind:key="index" @mouseover="list.deleteNote=index;" @mouseleave="list.deleteNote = -1">{{list.fruit}}
  <p v-if="list.deleteNote === index">{{list.note}}</p>
 </li>
</ul>
```

When hovering you set `deleteNote` to the current index, and at mouseover you set it to an invalid index (-1 in this case). The delete button is now tied to the current index.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the codesandbox here on StackOverflow supports `vue.js`, so I kind of tweaked the JS in the following fiddle. First, the entire list needs to be wrapped as a variable per the [Vue list rendering documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html).

See my fiddle with your code, and I think the desired outcome, here: https://jsfiddle.net/gve4s87L/